# How to integrate toggle button to Bootstrap 3.3.7?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, togglebutton

I have a site with Drupal 8 and Bootstrap 3.3.7

How to integrate toggle button?

I want to embed a rounded button with customizable text inside.

I did some research in Google and found only old library for older versions of bootstrap.

Here is an example:
[image: toggle switch button]

Comment: Have you even tried anything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HTML:**

```
<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" checked>
  <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>
```

**CSS:**

```
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

.switch input {display:none;}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

*You can also add the text via implementing and manipulating JS code.*

Comment: Thank you. I applied your code but it does not look like my example

Comment: Yes, it can but, of course, it should be styled separately.

Comment: @KamranPoladov how can i add a label left to the button?

Answer (score 0):

looks like you need a switch

```
<!-- Default checked -->

<label class="bs-switch">
  <input type="checkbox" checked>
  <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>
```

this is a standard bootstrap component so you would just need this code and modify the labels depending on how you want it to look.

also read over this link it has a lot of resources for switches https://mdbootstrap.com/components/bootstrap-switch/

Comment: This is not the bootstrap of version 3.3.7